# AJAX loading page within page

Tags: php, ajax, authentication

I have an AJAX script which validates a login script, when the user has entered in the incorrect data, the error message comes up, but when the user inputs correct data, the new page loads in the error message space. I understand where the problem is, I just do not know how to fix it.

Below is the login script and the checklogin script

login.php

```
<table class="loginTable" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td>
            Email:
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Password:
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="2">
            <span id="ErrorMessage"></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center">
            <!--Keep me logged in? <input type="checkbox" name="keeploggedin" /><br /><br />-->
            <input  id="loginButton" type="button" name="login" value="Login" onclick="processLogin()"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>


<script>

    function processLogin()
{
var xmlhttp;

var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() 
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("ErrorMessage").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("POST","checklogin.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("email=" + email + "&password=" + password);
}

</script>
```

checklogin.php

```
<?php

session_start();

//Login Script



//Variables
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$userPassword = $_REQUEST['password'];
//$keeploggedin = $_REQUEST['keeploggedin'];



require_once("dbdetails.php");

// Create Mysqli object
$db = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $database);

// Create statement object
$stmt = $db->stmt_init();

// Create a prepared statement
if($result = $stmt->prepare("SELECT u.UserFirstName, u.UserSurname, u.UserID FROM user u WHERE u.UserEmail = ? AND u.UserPassword = ?")) {

    // Bind your variables to replace the ?s
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $email, $userPassword) or die(errorCodes($stmt->errno));

    //$row -> fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    // Execute query
    $stmt->execute() or die(errorCodes($stmt->errno));

    $stmt->bind_result($fname, $sname, $userID);

    $stmt->store_result();

    $count = $stmt->num_rows;

    if($count == 1){
        while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {

            // Register $email, $password, $firstname, $surname, create logged_in session and redirect to file "projects.php"
            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
            $_SESSION['password'] = $userPassword;
            $_SESSION['firstname'] = $fname;
            $_SESSION['surname'] = $sname;
            $_SESSION['userID'] = $userID;
            $_SESSION['LoggedIn'] = 'true';
            $_SESSION['loginCount'] = 0;
            header("location:projects.php");
        }
    }
    else {
        //$_SESSION['loginCount'] += 1;
        //header("location:loginPage.php");
        //echo("<script type='text/javascript'>\n");
        //echo("changeError();\n");
        //echo("</script>");    

        echo("Username and Password mismatch, please try again");
    }

    // Close statement object
    $stmt->close();
}


    function errorCodes($aErrorCode)    {
        echo("Error " . $aErrorCode . " has occured");
    }


?>
```

Comment: why are you using something so primitive? ever heard of Jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test `xmlhttp.responseText` :

```
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
       if(xmlhttp.responseText != "")    //If not, it completes your error box
          document.getElementById("ErrorMessage").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
       //Else, let the redirection trigger

    }
```

Comment: After tweaking your code< i eventually got your method to work

Answer (score 0):

When login is successful return some json data saying that login is successful (from php), and then modify your this code

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() 
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("ErrorMessage").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
```

To redirect user to next page if you get `success` in response from php.

Answer (score 0):

with the simple ajax, hope it helps :)

```
<script>
function processlogin()
{
$.ajax(
{
url:'checklogin.php',
type:'POST',
data:{'email':email,'password':password},
success:function(xyz)
{
if(xyz==1)
{
$("#errormessage").load("ajax/newcontent.php");
}
else{
//do something as you need
}
}
});
}
</script>

in the checklogin.php page, if the IF condition success then 'echo 1' or 'echo 0' in else part.so that you can validate using these values in success block of the ajax script.
```